# 413 Request Entity Too Large in wcf service when uploading large image file

Tags: wcf, base64, rest-client

i have created wcf Service in which i am receiving Base64 string and converting base64 string to image to store in my project.

but when i am calling my wcf service method from rest client like this i am getting error like this:

**413 Request Entity Too Large**

and sometimes nothing happens when i am calling my wcf method from rest client.

[image]

above is how i am calling my wcf service method.

above base 64 string is an image of size 177Kb.

but when i am passing small base64 string of image with size 2 kb or 3 kb then my wcf service method is calling.

this is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

i have search alot on internet and added this:

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

but error is still not resloved.

can anybody please help me???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you have defined a `basicHttpBinding` with larger than default values, you have not told the WCF service to actually *use* that binding.   When no service endpoints are defined, the default out of the box binding is `basicHttpBinding` with the **default** values.

You can either set your defined binding as the default binding configuration for any services using `basicHttpBinding` that use that config file by omitting the `name` attribute in the binding definition, like this:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" 
                    maxStringContentLength="8388608" 
                    maxArrayLength="16384" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

OR you can assign the defined binding to an explicit endpoint, which would look something like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
              contract="MyNamespace.IServiceContract" />
    </endpoint>
  </service>
```

A third place to check is the IIS maximum request length:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you're uploading very large files you may also want to look at [chunking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Whole `<system.serviceModel>`**

**Option 1:** With default binding defined (omitting `name` attribute from binding configuration)

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
               maxBufferSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" 
                      maxStringContentLength="8388608" 
                      maxArrayLength="16384" 
                      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  </protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                             multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Option 2:** With explicit endpoint using specified binding configuration via endpoint's `bindingConfiguration` attribute:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
               maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
               maxBufferSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" 
                      maxStringContentLength="8388608" 
                      maxArrayLength="16384" 
                      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="MyService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
                contract="MyNamespace.IServiceContract" />
      </endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  </protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                             multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Either one of these options should resolve the issue.  If they don't, try the third option I gave in my original answer.